# Hover to reveal overlay - almost there, just needs some tweaks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've managed to cobble together a pretty good jQuery 'hover over image to reveal overlay' but there are a few niggles I was hoping someone much better at jQuery might be able to help with.

There's a link at the bottom to a JSFiddle

User hovers over image and an overlay slides up from the bottom.

I'd like this to work on mobile as well. From testing this on mobile, hover works but the overlay remains visible, so that's why I've added a close button.

**Two problems:**

1. The close button uses slideDown to hide the overlay, this messes up the slideToggle. **Is there another way to hide the overlay?** I'm using .hide to hide the overlay on page load.
2. I've used stop() to stop animation build up on the hover, which works well but does create a rather harsh effect if the mouse is pulled away before the animation is complete. **Is there a way to allow the animation to finish and pause before sliding back down?**

I've been scratching my head all afternoon trying to figure this out - any hep would be much appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box g6">
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Demo">
    <div class="info-block">
        <p>
            <strong>Title Here</strong>
        </p>
        <p class="description">
            <em>Duis ornare interdum ornare integer id vulputate sapien suspendisse quis mauris enim proin eleifend pharetra orci, quis feugiat massa molestie non.</em>
        </p>
        <a class="btn" href="#">Read more</a>
        <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

<div class="box g6">
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Demo">
    <div class="info-block">
        <p>
            <strong>Title Here</strong>
        </p>
        <p class="description">
            <em>Duis ornare interdum ornare integer id vulputate sapien suspendisse quis mauris enim proin eleifend pharetra orci, quis feugiat massa molestie non.</em>
        </p>
        <a class="btn" href="#">Read more</a>
        <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  $(document).ready( function() {

  $(".info-block").hide();

  $('.box').hover(
  function() {
  $(this).find('.info-block').stop(true,true).slideToggle().show();
  }
  );

  $( ".close" ).click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.info-block').slideUp();
  });
  });
```

**CSS**

```
 .box {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width:350px;

 }

 .info-block {
background: cyan;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
padding:10px;
height: 100%;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/StephenMeehan80/6mxLvbgq/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this :

```
$('.box').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.info-block').stop(true).slideDown();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.info-block').stop(true).slideUp();
}).find(".info-block").hide().find(".close").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.info-block').trigger('mouseleave');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fdyuae13/)**

`.stop(true)` stops any current animation stone dead and clears the animation queue.

`.stop(true, true)` would also send the animation to its final state, which would be unnatural here.

`.slideDown()` and `.slideUp()` avoid the mess caused by `.slideToggle()` after clicking the close button.

`.trigger('mouseleave')` is a tidy way to do `.stop(true).slideUp()` without having to repeat any code.

Comment: This is a very nice solution! Thanks Roamer-1888, it works a like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  Basically I changed it from hover to mouseenter and mouseleave, because your state is more dependent on the location of the mouse after you click on the close button.

```
$(document).ready( function() {


$(".info-block").hide();

$('.box').mouseenter(
  function() {
      if ($(this).find('.info-block').is(":hidden"))
        $(this).find('.info-block').stop(true,true).slideToggle().show();
  }
  );

    $('.box').mouseleave(
  function() {
      if (!$(this).find('.info-block').is(":hidden"))
        $(this).find('.info-block').stop(true,true).slideToggle();
  }
  );


$( ".close" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.info-block').slideToggle(function(){return false;});
});


});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you get better animations (when compared to `stop()`) using CSS. Though I am not sure how you would incorporate a close button with CSS alone. JQuery is very good at manipulating classes however. I would convert this to use a CSS class based approach. Also, you should be explicit with `addClass/removeClass` in the hover function, especially if the state can be toggled elsewhere.

JS

```
$('.box').hover(
  function() {
      $(this).find('.info-block').addClass("on");
  },
function() {
      $(this).find('.info-block').removeClass("on");
  });

$( ".close" ).click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.info-block').removeClass("on");
});
```

CSS

```
.info-block {
    background: cyan;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    bottom:0;
    transition:all .5s ease-in;
}
.info-block.on {
    height:100%;
    padding:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6mxLvbgq/5/

If you really want to stick with jQuery animations, you should look into using `if ($el.is(':animated')) return;` instead of `stop()`. This will let the animation finish without queuing up another one.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I'll take a look at the jQuery solution you kindly posted. I need to use jQuery for cross-browser compatibility, older versions of IE don't support CSS3 animations.

Comment: `.stop(true)` is good, but not `.stop(true,true)`. The second `true` means 'jumpToEnd' which, if user does a quick mouseover/mouseout, will be unnatural in this case.

Comment: The stop never actually triggers. I was lazy.